# What is the difference between Plaintext and Innertext of an element in Simple HTML dom parser in PHP?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

What is the difference between Plaintext and Innertext of an element in Simple HTML dom parser in PHP?

Example:

```
$html->find('title')[0]->innertext
$html->find('title')[0]->plaintext
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Simple HTML DOM parser documentation](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm#section_dump) the difference is next:

```
$html = str_get_html("<div>foo <b>bar</b></div>");
$e = $html->find("div", 0);

echo $e->tag; // Returns: " div"
echo $e->outertext; // Returns: " <div>foo <b>bar</b></div>"
echo $e->innertext; // Returns: " foo <b>bar</b>"
echo $e->plaintext; // Returns: " foo bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Plaintext:**

Plain text is used to find Element based on their tag names.
Example:
below example will find title.
$html->find('title')[0]->plaintext

**Innertext**
as name suggest Innertext is used to manipulate inner content of tags.
Example:
below example will find tag.
$html->find('h1')[0]->innertext